# Logging Flask Requests separately: How to remove Python Logging Handler by ID

Tags: python, flask, logging

So I have the following problem:

I am using Flask and I want generate two different kinds of Log files: One general Log file, which logs everything into one file, and one Logger/Handler, which logs only the incoming request and corresponding outgoing response, with a separate file for each request. In practice I am using a custom Log Class with custom levels and easy to call functions. But I tried to break it down to its basics:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
general_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# add_handlers_to_general_logger()

@app.before_request
def log_incoming_request():
    request_id = get_current_request_id()
    unique_logger = logging.getLogger("{0}.{1}".format(__name__, request_id))
    # add_handler_to_unique_logger()
    unique_logger.info("INCOMING REQUEST")


@app.route('/')
def index():
    general_logger.info("Index called!")
    file_A.do_something_A()  # this function takes X seconds to process, general_logger is also used in there
    return "Hello World"


@app.after_request
def log_outgoing_response(response):
    request_id = get_current_request_id()  # same id as in before_request
    unique_logger = logging.getLogger("{0}.{1}".format(__name__, request_id))
    unique_logger.info("OUTGOING RESPONSE")
    return response
```

Now the problem is that, although it works, I think it's not a good idea to create that many different loggers. The function called in index() takes an unknown amount of seconds to process, depending on sent request data, and multiple request should be able to be handled at once. My idea would be to just remove the corresponding handler in @app.after_request.

So, the question is:
How can I, after adding a specific Handler in @app.before_request, properly remove the right handler by name in @app.after_request like:

```
@app.before_request
def log_incoming_request():
    request_id = get_current_request_id()
    unique_logger = logging.getLogger("unique")

    add_handler_to_unique_logger(request_id)

    unique_logger.info("INCOMING REQUEST")

@app.after_request
def log_outgoing_response(response):
    request_id = get_current_request_id()  # same id as in before_request
    unique_logger = logging.getLogger("{0}.{1}".format(__name__, request_id))
    unique_logger.info("OUTGOING RESPONSE")

    unique_logger.removeHandler(request_id)

    return response
```

Or is there any other way to properly log the separate request log files (with request_id in their filename)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about memory management until it becomes a problem. In any case, you can delete the reference the logging module holds with:

```
del logging.root.manager.loggerDict[unique_logger_id]
```

The logger object itself will of course only stop existing if all other references to it that you have in your code are also gone. If you are also using unique handlers I also recommend to call `close()` on them so the used file resources are cleaned.